# How to get Spring beans related via @Autowired or property setter

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, autowired

I'd like to split one Spring application context (java app) which uses `<context:annotation-config />` and multiple `<context:component-scan ../>` but don't know how exactly are beans related there.

Application Context (BeanFactory) provides list of available beans and for each bean I'd like to get a list of related beans - therefore those which are:

- marked as "dependsOn" - those I'm able to get from the BeanDefinition
- used as a constructor reference
- used to fulfill @Autowired
- used to as a property/setter reference
- ... are there any other relations?

Having such relations (matrix) I'll be able to identify where to cut - which beans can be moved into new (smaller) application context (java app), which has to be exported/accessed through WS/RMI etc

Is there any way how to extract such relations from the application context object? how to get such relation matrix/graph?

Answer (score 0):

In a Spring application, the wiring validation is done at boot time. You can build your own "extractor" with two separate Junit test. Slowly separate your app and test often the app.

Comment: how to build such "extractor" - yes I know that wiring is done at boot time and application context provides me information about "dependsOn" relations but am not able to find that other wiring information. ... what was intended point in two separate Junit tests?